# MySQL got a strange behavior

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL query:

```
SET @from := "";
SET @to := "";
SELECT licensep INTO @from FROM car_system_vehicle WHERE ID = 1;
SELECT licensep INTO @to FROM car_system_vehicle WHERE ID = 2;
UPDATE car_system_vehicle SET licensep = @to WHERE ID = 2;
UPDATE car_system_vehicle SET licensep = @from WHERE ID = 1;
```

to replace two values `licensep`.

I can successfully run it with phpMyAdmin but console returns an error like this:

> FAIL: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

So what should I do with this problem?

Comment: It seems like the end of the error message is missing, isn't there more to it?

Comment: The end of the error message is the whole mysql code that I declared above

Comment: Do you have by any chance an un-closed (no `;`) query above that piece of code?

Comment: *The end of the error message is the whole mysql code that I declared above* You MUST citate 100% of error message, and WITHOUT any edition.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need in variables for to swap the values in 2 records:

```
UPDATE car_system_vehicle t1, car_system_vehicle t2
SET t1.licensep = t2.licensep, t2.licensep = t1.licensep 
WHERE t1.id = 1 AND t2.id = 2;
```

The only condition that **must be guaranteed** is that the condition for each table must select **exactly one** record from it.